# Boolean turns into int number 904 in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, boolean, onclicklistener, data-class

I'm working on a quiz app for my project at university, and I'm trying to save button and boolean that states if the answer is correct or not in data class and save all buttons in a temporary list so I can add onclick listener for all of them later. But when I'm trying to access boolean value, it just turns into number 904. Here's my code regarding these buttons.

```
val ansBtnList: MutableList<ButtonDataClass> = mutableListOf()
--------------------------------------------------------------
val ans = ButtonDataClass(Button(this), quizToShow.getValue(planets[0]).answers[i].isRight)
--------------------------------------------------------------
ansBtnList.add(ans)
--------------------------------------------------------------
for (i in 0..3) {
        ansBtnList[i].btn.setOnClickListener { Log.d(null, ansBtnList[i].btn.right.toString()) }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: ButtonDataClass code:

```
data class ButtonDataClass (var btn: Button, var right: Boolean)
```

Comment: `ansBtnList[i].btn.right` is maybe not a boolean. Could you post that class?

Comment: @shkschneider done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the `right` that you think it is. `btn` is the button. The button has a `right` field that is related to its coordinate on screen. You should try `ansBtnList[i].right.toString()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

btn.right refers to `right` variable of `Button` class, not to the one present in the `ButtonDataClass`

replace: `ansBtnList[i].btn.setOnClickListener { Log.d(null, ansBtnList[i].btn.right.toString()) }`

with: `ansBtnList[i].btn.setOnClickListener { Log.d("your_tag_id", ansBtnList[i].right) }`

Answer (score 0):

Of course you are not accessing the right field. `ansBtnList[i].btn.right` gives you the right position of your button in pixels.
Rather do `ansBtnList[i].right`